# QGIS: How do I specify the layer for an get_feature expression in the model builder?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, layers, expression, getfeature

I'm trying to calculate a field (Field calculator 2) in the model builder with an `get_feature` expression which should look something like this `attributes(get_feature('LandUse_TD_HYBAS_dissolved_calc', 'NEXT_DOWN', "HYBAS_ID"))['Calc']` . The problem is that I don't know how to specify the layer. Normally I just enter the layer name `'LandUse_TD_HYBAS_dissolved_calc'` which worked as I did it outside of the model builder, but seemingly isn't working in the model builder because the layer I want to use is calculated by another field calculation one step ahead (Field calculator 1).

[image: Model]

I have also tried to enter `'@Field_calculator_1_OUTPUT'` to specify the layer which did not work either(Picture 2).

[image: Expression]

**What am I supposed to enter for the layer specification? Or is there another way to do it in the model builder?**

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer:

You have to use the `@layer` variable to access the previous layer. So the expression looks like this `attributes(get_feature(@layer, 'NEXT_DOWN', "HYBAS_ID"))['Calc']`.