# How can I execute a query on a layer with the Model Designer on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I've created a diagram on the Model Designer that gets one vector layer as input and then it executes a SQL query on it:

[image]

However, if I try to use the name of the input parameter on the query, it doesn't work:

[image]

I know it works perfectly fine if I use the name of the original layer that is outside the Model Designer. So, if I try `select * from originalName`, it will work. However, that's not very useful because this layer will change its name according to the layer that's being selected outside the Model Designer.

I've also seen this [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/367723/173457) where the answer says that I only need to use `@layer`, but I've tested it and it doesn't seem to apply to the `Execute SQL` node. How can I get the name of the vector layer that is inside the flow and use it inside the query in the `Execute SQL` node on the Model Designer?

Comment: Try naming it input1 as stated 3 lines above your query within the tool.

Comment: @MrXsquared I missed that detail :s... You're right, just using `input1` solves this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution ?